# Additional include directories for boost compilation in MSVC++ Community Edition

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build the boost library with MSVC++ 2015 community edition with icu, zlib and iconv support. Jam building system assumes that I have none of these. However, I actually do have these libraries, just not in the MSVC++'s global include path. Frankly, I have no idea from which end I'm supposed to sort this out. Global includes are clearly absent in the MSVC++2015. Boost help isn't informative on this matter (i.e. Additional include directories for custom builds).

```
- has_icu builds           : no  (cached)       
- zlib                     : no  (cached)                          
- iconv (libc)             : no  (cached)                          
- iconv (separate)         : no  (cached)                          
- icu                      : no  (cached)                          
- icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)                                           
- zlib                     : no  (cached)
```

Comment: Usually the details about this are in the boost libraries that use them. For ICU and iconv, look in [regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html) or [locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/locale/doc/html/building_boost_locale.html). For zlib and bz2 in [iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html). You just set the appropriate variables when you invoke bjam (e.g. `-sICU_PATH=d:/sdk/icu53`). Only Python (AFAIK) needs few settings in `project-config.jam`.

Comment: I saw these documents, but command line options provided there doesn't work. Particularly, "bjam include=F:/MY_ICU_DIR --toolset=toolset-name install" doesn't work. There is no documentation on "bjam imclude=..." either. bjam --help shows nothing relevant.

Comment: I don't know about the `include` parameter. For ICU I use `-sICU_PATH=d:/sdk/icu53`. This needs to point to a directory with pre-built ICU. Mine contains directories `bin`,`bin64`,`include`,`lib` and `lib64`. For ZLib I use `-sZLIB_SOURCE=d:/library/zlib_1_2_8`. This only needs to point to the unpacked source, the build system will compile it itself. Don't know about iconv, I don't use it, but I'd assume it will work in similar manner. I have those parameters after the `--toolset` parameter, but that may not be important.

Comment: I've tried -s already, it didn't work. Could you please give me your full command, not just -s key? I'll try it myself.